# time.sleep blocks flask request

Tags: flask, server-sent-events

I am implementing server sent events using flask. If I use time.sleep inside my function, the sse doesn't return anything and the request stays as pending in the browser. If I don't use sleep, there would be overload of responses in the browser, so I need to use some delay. Why is time.sleep blocking the request? Is there another way I can add time delay here?

```
def get_message():
    time.sleep(1.0)
    s="xyz" #some function here for our business logic
    return s


@app.route('/stream')
def stream():
    def eventStream():
        while True:
            yield 'data: {}\n\n'.format(get_message())
    return Response(eventStream(), mimetype="text/event-stream")
```

Comment: Why would you use the [tag:sse] tag after you'd already found [tag:server-sent-events]?  The popup description shows it obviously has nothing to do with the SSE you're talking about.

Comment: Well, sorry about that. I didn't realise SSE tag was for something else.

Comment: @DeepakBanka: pro tip: hover your mouse over a tag to get information as to its intended usage.